# What's the error about the definition of NP?

Tags: reference-request, definitions

Many sources (including [Wolfram's MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NP-CompleteProblem.html)) say that NP problem is defined as a decision problem "verifiable in nondeterministic polynomial time" (check Google to see more sources).

But accordingly [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=NP_(complexity)&oldid=1029888257) tells that NP are problems that can be solved in non-determnistic polynomial time.

From conjunction of these two statements it follows that $\mathrm{P}=\mathrm{NP}$, because any algorithm verifies itself.

So, apparently MathWorld and many others are wrong in their definition of NP? Or what do I misunderstand?

If "verifiable in nondeterministic polynomial time", is not a definition of NP, then how is it indeed called?

Answer (score 3):

If a problem $A$ is verifiable in polynomial-time by a non-deterministic Turing machine $T$ (given an instance of the problem and certificate of length polynomially bounded in the size of the instance) then it is also solvable in polynomial-time by a non-deterministic Turing machine $T'$.

The Turing machine $T'$ simply (non-deterministically) guesses the certificate (among all certificates having a polynomially-bounded length) and then (non-deterministically) checks whether each certificate candidate is valid using $T$.

This shows that $A \in \mathsf{NP}$.

Conversely, if a problem is in $\mathsf{NP}$ then it is verifiable in polynomial-time by a deterministic Turing machine $T$. Clearly, $T$ is also a non-deterministic Turing machine.

Answer (score 1):

The class $\mathsf{NP}$ can be defined either as

1. the class of languages that can be *verified by a deterministic polynomial time algorithm*;
2. the class of languages that can be *solved by a nondeterministic polynomial time algorithm*.

Regarding 1), a verification algorithm is a two-argument algorithm $A$, where one argument is an ordinary input string $x$, and the other argument is a binary string $y$ called a *certificate*. The algorithm $A$ verifies $x$ if there exists a $y$ such that $A(x,y)=1$. The language verified by a verification algorithm *A* is $L=\{ x \in \{0,1\}^* |$ there exists $y \in \{0,1\}^*$ such that $A(x,y)=1$.

Regarding 2), defining

$\operatorname{NTIME}_{\operatorname{TM}}(T(n)) = \{R: \exists$ a nondeterministic Turing Machine with time complexity $O(T(n))$ on *any computation path* that accepts $R\}$

then $\mathsf{NP} = \operatorname{NTIME}_{\operatorname{TM}}(n^{O(1)})$

Regarding Wolfram's MathWorld, it is worth noting here that the same web site (see their definition of [NP-Problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NP-Problem.html)) reports that "A problem is assigned to the $\mathsf{NP}$ (nondeterministic polynomial time) class if it is solvable in polynomial time by a nondeterministic Turing machine."